# Creating abootable USB for use on Acer Aspire One using a Macbook

Tags: usb-drive, macbook, aspire-one

Last night I tried to upgrade an Acer Aspire One that my granddaughter uses to Ubuntu 12.0.4 but it failed before it finished and now the machine won't start at all. I've had a look at how to create a bootable USB but the instructions don't seem to cater for cross platform situations.

I have a Macbook running Snow Leopard and I want to create a bootable USB that will allow me to restore the Acer Aspire One to a working state running Ubuntu 12.0.4.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use unetbootin it has a Mac OS X version;-)

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Also, tuxboot which is more specific to clonezilla, gparted, Tux2Live etc. Unfortunately it does NOT have pre-compiled binary for OS X...

http://tuxboot.org/

Comment: Glad to be of help;-)